# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not working correctly in Joomla. Replaces instead of appends data in table

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm working on a component where I am loading data from a CSV file to the mySQL database.  I'm using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.  It works great except for one thing.  In Joomla the query replaces all of the data in the table.  (It truncates the table and then add the new data).  I just want it to insert the new rows at the bottom of the table.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$loaddata_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/data/mydata.csv'"
."\n INTO TABLE  myDataTable"
."\n FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
."\n OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '" . "\"" . "'"
."\n LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
."\n IGNORE 1 LINES"
."\n (column1,column2,column3);                     

$db->setQuery($loaddata_query);
$result = $db->query();
```

Like I say, this works great for importing the data, but replaces all of the records. However if I echo $loaddata_query and I copy and paste it into phpMyAdmin, it works correctly.  Here's the echoed query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/data/mydata.csv'
TO TABLE myDataTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(column1,column2,column3)
```

I can't seem to figure out the difference.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.2.3

Comment: Sorry to bother everyone.  This error was self-inflicted.  For another application (from which I copied the code) I had included some code to truncate the table.  This is what was causing the problem, not the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command.

Doh!!!

Answer (score 0):

Normally this shouldn't be happening as phpmyadmin is php, so maybe joomla has a `TRUNCATE` before the `LOAD` but in all cases try using `IGNORE` keyword

Like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE IGNORE 'c:/data/mydata.csv'
TO TABLE myDataTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(column1,column2,column3)
```

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.  Plus I'm already using IGNORE at the bottom of the query to ignore lines in the file.  Any other suggestions?